# Prevent absolute-right-positioned DIV from overlapping content at windows-resizing

Tags: css, html, positioning

I hope you can help me on this. I was searching Google etc. for 1 hour but nothing works 
I have a absolut DIV that is on the top, right side of the browser.

How do I prevent, that, when the browser is horizontally resized, it goes more in the center than eg. 400px from the horizontal-center of the page?

Can't be too hard, but I have no clue anymore.

Comment: I assume your `div` has `position: fixed;`?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions:

1. Try using `float: right;` instead of absolute positioning the div.
2. Use media queries to adjust the value of 'right' as the browser size changes, for example:

> ```
> .rightDiv {
>     right: 5px;
> }
> @media (min-width: 720px) { 
>     .rightDiv {
>         right: 50px;
> }
> @media (min-width: 960px) { 
>     .rightDiv {
>         right: 100px;
>     }
> }
> ```